# Sidekiq on railscast. Still have some questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I was watching the RailsCast on Sidekiq and had some questions:

1) Sidekiq handles tasks through threads instead of processes. What does this mean? Why does it save on memory?

2) Does the method inside the worker class need to have a "perform" method?

3) On the Sidekiq docs, it says:

> Start sidekiq from the root of your Rails application so the jobs
>   will be processed:
>
> bundle exec sidekiq

So if I'm running this on localhost, I can run bundle exec sidekiq. If I pushed up to Heroku, what do I do now? How do I run Sidekiq on Heroku?

4) I am not sure if my Sidekiq is working. I have this code:

```
def set_defaults
    self.clicks = 0 if clicks.blank?
    self.title = TitleWorker.perform_async(orig_url)
end
```

But TitleWorker.perform_asynch(orig_url) in testing just seems to return a string of numbers. What is going on? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not super clear about the first question, I might be able to answer the other questions you have:

2. Yes. It needs a Perform method to start the worker process.
3. Heroku is just amazing. You don't have to do any special configuration on Heroku for running Sidekiq. All you have to do is, just make sure `RedisToGo` is installed, and add this to the Procfile:

`worker:  bundle exec rake jobs:start
sidekiq: bundle exec sidekiq -c 15 -v`

Comment: Your Procfile is starting both Resque and Sidekiq for some reason.